# Can you use the ebay api to have a checkout on your own site?

Tags: ebay-api

The developer site, https://www.x.com/developers/ebay , is very unclear about this. Is it possible to display "buy now" products on your site, and to allow people to do a "checkout" on your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ebay has discontinued the ThirdPartyCheckout program and now requires checkout to be processed through ebay.com.

Comment: Is it still true in 2016 that we cannot use eBay API to implement checkout in a mobile app?

Comment: @bahmed If you have the answer to your question can you please share it?